# How to track changes in linktable with System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm using DbChangeTracker in my c#/asp.net project (Visual Studio 2017, Entity Framework 6.4.4), which works fine. However, I've problems with tracking all changes in tables in combination of a link table.

Example: two classes, bread and topping and a link table goodCombination

```
class bread {
  public string name;
  public int tasteScore;
}
class topping {
  public string name;
  public bool containsLactose;
}
class goodCombination {
  string breadName;   //foreign key to field name of class bread
  string toppingName; //foreign key to field name of class topping
}
```

In EF the class goodCombination isn't a seperate class but part of the two classes bread and topping:

```
class bread {
  public string name;
  public int tasteScore;
  public virtual ICollection<topping> toppings
}
class topping {
  public string name;
  public bool containsLactose;
  public virtual ICollection<bread> breads
}
```

**My problem is**: changes in bread.name and bread.tasteScore are trackable.
Changes in bread.toppings are *not trackable*!
That means:

```
var allChangedEntities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(c => c.Entity is IChangeTrackableObject && c.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
```

results in an empty list, even when a goodCombination is added or changed.

**My question is: how to track these changes?**